# How to create nested elements with classes inside li using jQuery

Tags: jquery

HELP! i'm stuck trying to create a nested li element with divs and other stuff in it with jQuery:

thats the html block im trying to create dynamically using jQuery:

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <div class="flex-row">
              <img src="/images/baseline_account_circle_black_48dp.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="">
            </div>
         </a>
        <div class="info-dropdown">

        </div>
        </li>
```

i tried this and it's not working.

```
$("<li>",
  {
    'class': "nav-item"
  })
  .append($("<a>",
         {
           'class':"nav-link",
           attr:"#"
         })
  .append($("<div>",
  {
    'class':'flex-row'
  })
  .append($("<img>",
  {
    width:'40px',
    height:'40px',
    'src': "/images/baseline_account_circle_black_48dp.png"
  })
  .append($("<div>",
  {
    'class':'info-dropdown'
  })
  .appendTo( $("#sidebar ul.nav");
```

Comment: You're appending the elements to `<li>`, not the newly-created child elements.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks i got it. created the var li first then i added all the rest to it and then i added the li to my pre-created ul. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is stuck like i was here's what worked for me:

```
var li = $("<li>",
  {
    'class': "nav-item"
  })
  .append($("<a>",
         {
           'class':"nav-link",
           'href':"#"
          })
  .append($("<div>",
  {
    'class':'flex-row'
  })
  .append($("<img>",
  {
    width:'40px',
    height:'40px',
    'src': "/images/baseline_account_circle_black_48dp.png"
  }))));
  $(li).append($("<div>",
  {
    'class':'info-dropdown'
  }));
  $("#sidebar ul.nav").append(li);
```

basically i created the var li first. then i added (append() ) all the other stuff to it. then i added another div to it because that's what it wanted and after i added ALL this to my pre-created ul element.